# css grand child of first item selection

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/jg69c3yf/1/

I am a css noob. 
I want to select the div having `arrow-right` but it should be inside the div class having `active` as the first child anywhere in a div.

In this fiddle, Only 3 should have the color green.

**HTML** :

```
<div class="owl-stage">
<div class="owl-item">
1 
</div>
<div class="owl-item">
2 
</div>

<div class="owl-item active">
<div class="item">
 <div class="arrow-right">
3 

 </div>
</div>


</div>
<div class="owl-item active">
<div class="item">
 <div class="arrow-right">
4 
 </div>
</div>

<div class="owl-item active">
<div class="item">
 <div class="arrow-right">
5 

 </div>


</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.owl-stage .owl-item.active:first-child {

background-color:red;
color:blue;

}


.owl-stage .owl-item.active:first-child .arrow-right {
background-color:red;
color:Green;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you seem to have missing `</div>` end tags in your HTML; this becomes visible when indenting things properly.
I added the `</div>` in now, so you should shout out if I did it wrong!

Anyway, the answer is that what you want is possible in CSS, but only if you use a little trick. Apparently, the designers never realized that this was needed. The trick is to first colourise "all .owl-item.active divs" and then reset the colours back to the default for "all .owl-item.active divs following other .owl-item.active divs".

```css
.owl-stage .owl-item.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
}

.owl-stage .owl-item.active .arrow-right {
  background-color: red;
  color: Green;
}

.owl-stage .owl-item.active ~ .owl-item.active {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}

.owl-stage .owl-item.active ~ .owl-item.active .arrow-right {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-stage">
  <div class="owl-item">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item">
    2
  </div>

  <div class="owl-item active">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="arrow-right">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="owl-item active">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="arrow-right">
        4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- added this end tag -->
  
  <div class="owl-item active">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="arrow-right">
        5
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- and this one -->
```

Comment: This one is better than temani's answer because it works on the principles on inherit rather than me explicitly setting values.

Comment: Pretty strange that: `.owl-stage > .active:not(:last-child) .arrow-right {
  color: green;
}` works but `.owl-stage > .active:first-child .arrow-right {
  color: green;
}` doesn't. Though, it works if you also add the active class to the first / other two as well, weird...should have worked.

Comment: @VXp That's because in this particular example, there is no .active element that's also the first child of its parent (.owl-stage), while there _IS_ an .active element that is the last child of .owl-stage.

Comment: Yea but the logic for the :first-child should be to target it no matter its position inside its parent, but ok if we take your statement into account, then the :first-of-type should do that instead, but it doesn't. :first-child shouldn't target only the first element inside another one, imho.

Comment: @VXp Sorry, but I'm not sure I follow. That's the very definition of :first-child, that it is the first child! What would your definition be then?

Comment: What's the point of having another class somewhere among all the children but you can't target it with the :first-child selector, what I'm saying is that its definition/logic is false imho, but ok, lets say its ok as it is, then you should target it with the :first-of-type but again you can't. Imho, it should target the first element with that class no matter its position, because it is the first element with that class which also makes it the first child with that class. I don't agree with the current behavior, not logical.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```css
.owl-stage .owl-item .arrow-right{
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
}

/* Here you have the Selector for the first active class*/
.owl-stage .owl-item.active .arrow-right{
  background-color: white;
  color: Green;
}
/**/


/* You should put the stlye back as the first selector */
.owl-stage .owl-item.active+.owl-item .arrow-right{
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-stage">
  <div class="owl-item">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item active">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="arrow-right">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item active">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="arrow-right">
        4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item active">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="arrow-right">
        5
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I want to get hold of this class 'arrow-right' inside the first active child.